# How do I read application properties in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

I integrated AWS SES API to my Micronaut Groovy application using guide [send mail in micronaut](http://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-email-groovy/guide/index.html) and I am able send mails if I directly assign values to properties.

I want to make it config driven hence have been trying to find ways to achieve that.

I tried @Value annotation as mentioned in guide but was not able to make it work.

```
@Value("aws.secretkeyid")
String keyId
```

Further digging into documentation revealed that Micronaut has its own annotation for injecting properties in variables.

```
@Property(name="aws.secretkeyid")
String keyId
```

But nothing seems to work, my variables are still null.

What could be possibly wrong here ?

For reference, following is in my application.yml file

```
aws:
  keyid: "2weadasdwda"
  secretkeyid: "abcdesdasdsddddd"
  region: "us-east-1"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using it incorrectly, you are injecting the literal value `aws.secretkeyid`, not the value of a variable.

The correct syntax is (Groovy):

```
@Value('${aws.secretkeyid}')
String keyId
```

Notice that you must use single quotes to avoid Groovy to attempt interpolation

Java:

```
@Value("${aws.secretkeyid}")
String keyId;
```

Kotlin:

```
@Value("\${aws.secretkeyid}")
keyId: String
```

Notice that you must use a backslash to escape the dollar sign to avoid Kotlin string templates

Comment: The syntax you mentioned is for Java, not for Groovy.
I tried it first thing as it was in [send mail in micronaut] documentation, but code does not even compile if you use above syntax.

Comment: The syntax I posted is for Groovy and does compile indeed. Notice that you must use single quotes to avoid Groovy to attempt interpolation.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I made the mistake of using double quotes instead of single quotes. 
Although due to this silly mistake at my end, I ended up upgrading Micronaut version to 1.0.1 and used @Property(name = "aws.secretkeyid") :D

Comment: I was going to answer it myself but your answer is correct as per the question. :)

Comment: Just curious to know, if I have a different filename other than application.yml, how would I need to access the properties present in the different filename.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone else stumbles upon this problem, you also have alternative to use @Property annotation in Micronaut ( starting from version 1.0.1 )

Syntax is as follows

```
@Property(name = "your.application.property")
String propertyName
```

PS : This is what was mentioned in Micronaut Documentation but was not working in my case as I was on Micronaut Version 1.0.0

Comment: you need to add property in `application.properties` file. based on this link http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/10/micronaut-mastery-configuration.html